# Where are the images for the theme Twenty Eleven 1.2?

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven

In Twenty Eleven 1.2, where would I find the images that appear at the top of the blog -- in what folder?

I know one of the images is called 'lanterns.jpg', but I can't find it or the other ones.

Here's the site: http://richardclunan.com/

Thanks,

Comment: Can I suggest to visit http://www.borgyborgy.net It offers some free 1000x288 pixel size headers, to customize default TwentyEleven theme. Useful for blog beginners. It allows you to easily customize a standard installation, allowing a newbie to have a customized and ready blog in a few minutes. All images are taken by me and provided under a Creative Commons 3.0 License.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are in the `/images/headers/` directory. [Here they are in SVN](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/twentyeleven/1.3/images/headers/).

#### Edit

Full path: `/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/headers/`

Comment: i still can't find that...where's /images/header/ ?

Comment: How can you not find them? I **Linked to them**. They are part of the Twenty Eleven Theme; thus the `/images/headers/` directory is *inside the Twenty Eleven Theme directory*. See updated answer.

Comment: you will need to use ftp or the file management system of your hoster to access these images.

Comment: thanks -- i found those images on my server. I was confused with the SVN thing, but that full path got me it. thanks chip